# positioning RightToLeft controls in canvas

Tags: wpf, layout

i have a canvas that users can add some controls from toolbox to it, I have a PropertyGrid that binds to selected control in canvas.

My problems are listed below:

1. when one control is selected from canvas, some it's properties listed in PropertyGrid. When I change some of these properties (For example:FontFamily,FontSize,Foreground) the appearance of selected control is not changed but it's `FontFamily` changed properly,
   some other properties work fine (for example:Width,Height,FlowDirection)
2. I save the properties of controls in a xml file, When I load the xml file and add controls to a cleared canvas according to xml data,
   the positioning of RightToLeft controls is incorrect but LeftToRight controls aligned correctly, (the Left coordinate of RightToLeft controls aligned to Right coordinate of it) see below:

For LeftToRight Controls:
[image]
For RightToLeft Controls:

[image]

Comment: which attached property of canvas do you save and load for each control? Canvas.Left? Canvas.Right? or both?

Comment: If you put each control in a simple grid with Flow=LeftToRight then it should make the second problem go away. right?

Comment: i do:  var q1 = new Grid() { FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight };
                        q1.Children.Add(item);
                        myCanvas.Children.Add(q1);
but,the problem already exist.

Comment: Can't say for sure it could be a bug. can you post some of your code?